# How to avoid "dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found" error while building web player app?

Tags: mysql, dll, unity-game-engine

I have Mysql.Data.dll in my project. I know that it's unavailable to build app with mysql for web player, but when I removeing Mysql.Data.dll it says that MySql not found. I really use mysql but only in server scene (client-server app) and client scene that I build for web player have no dependencies with MySQL. How can I build my client scene that doesn't use MySQL for web player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Unity builds all source code when building a player, so one way I can think of in your case is to split the project in à client and server project, then build client.

The other option is to use conditional compilation in your scripts, but that may implies more code source changes. You will also need to put the DLL in the according Plugin folder, so it is only used with the right platform. (Thanks to [Chanibal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785171/chanibal))

Comment: You won't have to remove the plugin if you put in the right directory. For example, `Assets/Plugins/x86` and `Assets/Plugins/x86_64` copies only to the native builds.